# crystal reports - display RTF data

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I am currently working in the Crystal Reports.

Please anyone tell me how to convert the **RTF file data** (that are retrieved by dataset)
to display in the crystal report Text Object.

I tried the following things,

1. `@Text` field object right click select **Format Object-> Paragraph tag, selects Text Interpretation as RTF Text.**
2. In formula field i typed `{DT.Text_Description}`

But I am not getting the Text in the report.

Anyone help me.

Comment: It could be that RTF-like data is not well-formed; Crystal seems to be somewhat picky about RTF syntax. Unfortunately I have no specific knowledge, what elements must be present in RTF to allow CR render it properly. You may post contents of your RTF field (some shorter example of course), maybe we can find, what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You did well, this is the right way to display RTF data.
Maybe a typo error; instead o typing the field could you click on tha available fields?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i selects the available fields now but 'm not getting the output in the crystal view

Comment: Now i got the output text than you for your answer.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? If my answer solved the problem you can 'accept' it

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report side is correct, but how you trasfer the data to data set, instead of text you should take RTF:

```
Me.Dset.Tables("Table").Rows(row).Item("ItemName") = RTBox.Rtf - correct

Me.Dset.Tables("Table").Rows(row).Item("ItemName") = RTBox.Text- Not correct
```